# How to read a PDF file, which is embedded into a html? Using java for selenium test

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, pdf

I am using selenium to automate this functionality

1. Click on the radio button
2. A new window opens with a URL that doesn't end with.pdf
3. The new window displays a form.
4. And this pdf form is embedded into HTML.
5. It's required just to parse this pdf file and assert text, on the browser itself.

Since selenium doesn't support pdf parsing, I have tried using pdfbox API, and that dint work as the URL is not ending with .pdf

And the test to be performed while the form is open on the window, so I can not use pdfbox API on the downloaded file in the local drive.

Is there a way to assert the pdf text?

Comment: Would be nice if you can share some of your code or the URL.

Comment: @SwaroopHumane, code looks like this-<embed name="ABC" style="XYZ" src="qwe" type="application/pdf">

Comment: pdfbox itself doesn't care about the filename, only about the content. It is important that this content is transmitted in binary form.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, yes, correct the issue is not with filename, it is more on how to read it as pdf content.